# How do I put a javascript variable inside javascript array?

Tags: javascript

I'm sure this is a simple question, but I couldn't find the answer.

I've included the code as well as my explanation.

```
var dates = "'2012-07-22','2012-07-26','2012-07-28'";
```

i have this JavaScript variable and i need to pass it the below `filterDates` array...something like this

```
filterDates = [dates];
```

or

```
filterDates = [document.write(dates)];

var filterDates = [];
```

I really don't know how to do it with JavaScript...for example we can do it in php like this

```
filterDates = [<?php echo $thatVariable; ?>];
```

How do I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: `var filterDates = ['2012-07-22','2012-07-26','2012-07-28']` is perfectly acceptable too by the way (not sure if you created `dates` just for this purpose)

Comment: actually i am getting dynamic dates with ajax get method..then passing the resposne data in a global javscript variable and now want to pass that variable in filterDates....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var filterDates = dates.split(',');
$.each(filterDates,function(i,val){
    filterDates[i] = val.split("'")[1];
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Use split

```
filterDates = dates.split(',')
```

That will give you the following array:

```
filterDates = ["'2012-07-22'","'2012-07-26'","'2012-07-28'"]
```

If you want them to be actual dates, rather than string representations of dates, you'll have to do some more processing, but I'm not sure that's what you're after at all?

```
filterDates.forEach(function(d, i) { 
    filterDates[i] = new Date(d.replace(/\'/g, ''));
});
```

Comment: i am trying to filter dates to unvailableDates in jquery date-picker....thanks...it's not printing them into filterDates array...